# How to view the header of an email in Gmail?

Tags: gmail

I would like to view the full header of an email message in Gmail. Is this feature allowed or are you only allowed to view it on the mailbox server on their side?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Open any email, then open the dropdown menu, and select the `show original` option:

[image: The GMail message view]

It will give you all the information about that email.

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22454?hl=en Please read it.